# Slow down execution speed of <a href=" ">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have multiple `href's` and I need to add a delay between when they are clicked and when they load. As there are hundreds of `hrefs` I cant have a separate js function for each one.

The two ways I have researched were, passing the contents of the href to javascript as a variable, such as:

```
<a href="example1.php">example1</a>
<a href="example2.php">example2</a>
<a href="example3.php">example3</a>
<script>
var href = ### CONTENTS OF SELECTED HREF ###
$(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = href;}, 1000);
  });        
});
```

Is it possible to do so using CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not doable using CSS (Cascading Style Sheets, No way). You would need to use Javascript.

But yes, you do not need to write different functions for every `a`, just fetch the `href` inside the click callback and then redirect the user accordingly.

```
$(function() {
  $("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = href;
    }, 1000);
  });        
});
```